# Xp_cmdshell and permissions

Tags: sql-server, xp-cmdshell

I have an SQL non-sysadmin user. I am running xp_cmdshell in stored procedures so I was having issues as expected. I configured a proxy account to allow to run this.

I've used the following blog's instructions to do this [Blog](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2007/08/23/xp-cmdshell-and-permissions.aspx)

I've successfully created a windows user for proxy account and I can run xp_cmdshell now .. but what I am facing is

> SQLState = 28000, NativeError = 18456
>   Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'domain\accountName'.
>   NULL

I couldn't find a workaround to this error.

where am I doing wrong..

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: What command are you running for `xp_cmdshell`? It could be permissions for what you are doing **outside** of SQL Server.

Comment: I am running bcp for xp_cmdshell\

Comment: check out the MSDN for permissions on bcp to rule them out as causing your error message https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx#Permissions

Comment: I've all the permission on that db like read/read etc

Comment: can there be any issue with account type ?

Comment: Possibly, you could be trying to pass a Windows Username as a SQL_Login. Can you add your `LOGIN` script and `bcp` command to your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138131/discussion-between-shaneis-and-usman-rana).